# Refire On Window Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have this full random graph bars script with Chart.js and canvas element.

When I resize the window by inspecting elements or testing in tablet/phone sizes the script, it doesn't resize(because of intended css), and interferes with my inspection process. I've tried to make the script re-fire on window resize, but I cannot get it to work, trying a few different methods.

Script:

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function(barChart) {
    (function() {
      var data = [],
        barsCount = 24,
        labels = new Array(barsCount),
        updateDelayMax = 500,
        $id = function(id) {
          return document.getElementById(id);
        },
        random = function(max) {
          return Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
        },
        helpers = Chart.helpers;
      Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
      for (var i = barsCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        data.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 100));
      };
      new Chart($id('header-random-bar-graph').getContext('2d')).Bar({
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
          fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.1)',
          data: data
        }]
      }, {
        showScale: false,
        barShowStroke: false,
        barValueSpacing: 1,
        showTooltips: false,
        onAnimationComplete: function() {
          var heroChart = this,
            timeout;
          this.options.onAnimationComplete = randomUpdate;
          this.options.animationEasing = 'easeOutQuint';
          randomUpdate();

          function randomUpdate() {
            heroChart.stop();
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
              var randomNumberOfBars = Math.floor(Math.random() * barsCount),
                i;
              for (i = randomNumberOfBars - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                heroChart.datasets[0].bars[Math.floor(Math.random() * barsCount)].value = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
              };
              heroChart.update();
            }, Math.random() * updateDelayMax);
          };
        }
      });
    })();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

I tried adding to the end:

```
$(window).resize(barChart);
```

Then I get the console error in Chrome that: "barChart is not defined".

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q44qbdov/4/ , but the fiddle doesn't display the issue properly.

Answer (score 2):

`barChart` is defined a few functions further in, you have to move it 2 lines further up than in your fiddle.

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function(barChart) { 
    //barChart is only defined within this closure
    (function() {
      //your code...
    })();
    $(window).resize(barChart);
  });

})(jQuery);
```

**Edit**

If I understand it correctly, you're trying to call the method you call on `$(document).ready` again when the window gets resized. One little modification to the above code does that:

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() { 
    //define a function to use it again as a handler
    function barChart() {
      //your code...
    });

    //execute the function
    barChart();

    //set function as resize event handler
    $(window).resize(barChart);
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Btw: I don't think you need

```
(function($) {...})(jQuery);
```

as well as

```
$(document).ready(function() {...});
```

But I may be wrong and that isn't really part of your question so, whatever :)

Comment: I did as you said, and it still doesn't seem to re-fire when the window is resized. https://jsfiddle.net/q44qbdov/14/

Comment: I've done as you have said, the script works, but still doesn't restart when window is resized.